# root login via SSH still enabled after setting PermitRootLogin to 'no'

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I'm trying to remove root access and password authentication over SSH to a RHEL server so that all users must access it using keys. So far the key access is set up and working, but I am unable to turn off password authentication across the board or disable the root account.

Below are the uncommented lines from my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file - am I missing something somewhere? I was under the impression that all that should be required to disable the root account is to switch PermitRootLogin from 'yes' to 'no' and to restart sshd, which I have done.

The output from ssh -vvv is also pasted below - it appears to me that none of the sshd_config settings are being applied here. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have now also pasted the output of `rpm-qa | grep -i ssh`, `grep "# config:" /etc/init.d/sshd` and `strings $(which sshd) | grep -i "sshd_config"`

grep "# config:" /etc/init.d/sshd

```
# config: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# config: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub
# config: /etc/ssh/ssh_random_seed
# config: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

strings $(which sshd) | grep -i "sshd_config"

```
/usr/sbin/sshx/etc/sshd_config (this file contains only one uncommented line - Subsystem       sftp    /usr/sbin/sshx/libexec/sftp-server)
```

rpm -qa | grep -i ssh

```
openssh-clients-4.3p2-36.el5_4.4
openssh-server-4.3p2-36.el5_4.4
openssh-4.3p2-36.el5_4.4
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin no 
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no 
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES 
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT 
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Output from ssh -vvv (IP removed)

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_33.33
debug1: match: OpenSSH_33.33 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 123/256
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host *.*.*.* filename /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host *.*.*.* filename /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 20
debug1: Host '*.*.*.*' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug2: bits set: 507/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7ff728c241f0)
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@*.*.*.*'s password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 63 padlen 17 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to *.*.*.* ([*.*.*.*]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env rvm_dump_environment_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_bin_path
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env rvm_clang_flag
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env rvm_verbose_flag
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env COMMAND_MODE
debug3: Ignored env __array_start
debug3: Ignored env rvm_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_debug_flag
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env Apple_Ubiquity_Message
debug3: Ignored env escape_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_prefix
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env _second
debug3: Ignored env rvm_version
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env _first
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env rvm_reload_flag
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you reload or restart sshd? Your sshd may still be using the old setting otherwise.

Comment: Yes I have restarted sshd, but nothing...

Comment: in that case, what does your secure log say when you login? also, try to use ssh -vvv to look at the output to see the exchange between the client and server to find any clue.

Comment: what is the actual file you modified? is it /etc/ssh/sshd_config? does it have lines such as Port? maybe not the correct file.

Comment: Now I'm a little concerned...

/var/log/secure -> empty file
/var/log/secure.1 -> doesn't exist
/var/log/secure.2 -> empty file
/var/log/secure.3 -> last entry 2 and a half weeks ago

Comment: Yeah no logs would be a concern, but your client output does

Comment: If you want to make sure you've updated the right config file, try this: `grep "# config:" /etc/init.d/sshd` ... The commented header of the init script of sshd contains the paths of the config files. If this doesn't work, try this: `strings $(which sshd) | grep -i "sshd_config"`

Comment: As for the logs, check /etc/syslog.conf (or rsyslog.conf if RHEL 6) for the string `authpriv`: `grep -i authpriv /etc/*syslog.conf`

Comment: Thanks Yanick. Have edited the results of sshd_config grep into the main post. the log grep returned:
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none  /var/log/messages
# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*      /var/log/secure

Answer (score 2):

running `strings $(which sshd) | grep -i "sshd_config"` found the file `/usr/sbin/sshx/etc/sshd_config`

Making config changes to this file has worked. As to why sshd is using this file I'm sure is another question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem :) Just out of curiosity though, try running this: `rpm -qa | grep -i ssh` and paste the result in your question. This will tell us if you have any special ssh packages installed. It's also possible your openssh-server package was actually installed from source and not from rpm?

Comment: Thanks again. I have pasted the data into the original question. Unfortunately I cannot tell you how openssh-server was installed, as I've only recently been tasked with looking after this particular server. It's certainly a possibility!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`DenyUser root`

That would block root from logging in via ssh.

`AllowUser jack jill`

Will also limit who logs in via ssh.